# Does a row within a container require span12? Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am using bootstrap for the first time to work on a project of mine. And from what I can tell container>row works fine, which begs the questions is container>row>span12 needed, or is it just best practice?

Thank you

Comment: In what context? can you clarify a bit more what exactly you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is confusing.

Bootstrap works by using a floated grid system. Looking at the source below should clear up what is going on. The `.container` class sets a width of 940px, as does the `.span12` class. The `.row` class is a div with a clearfix on it to contain a row of floated `.span` columns. All `.spanXX` classes are floated left and given 20px left margin to create the grid.

If all you are using is a container and a row, you are just creating a 940px wide container with -20px left-margin. You should still use `.span12` to keep consistent with the framework and set the margin correctly. This raises the question, why are you using a grid layout in the first place if you don't want to take advantage of the columns. If all you want is a 940px container then just create one.

From bootstrap.css:

```
.row {
  margin-left: -20px;
  *zoom: 1;
}

.row:before,
.row:after {
  display: table;
  line-height: 0;
  content: "";
}

.row:after {
  clear: both;
}

[class*="span"] {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.container,
.navbar-static-top .container,
.navbar-fixed-top .container,
.navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
  width: 940px;
}

.span12 {
  width: 940px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation, if I understand your question correct, the answer lies in this link [Bootstrap documentation](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem). Scroll a little bit down to Fluid Nesting.

Also keep in mind when a new container is created within a span the count starts at '0' so

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12">
    Fluid 12
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span6">
        Fluid 6
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span6">Fluid 6</div>
          <div class="span6">Fluid 6</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="span6">Fluid 6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this example code you can see that there is a span 12 which is the main div. With in this span there 2 spans of 6! That makes sense, and in the span of 6 there a also 2 spans of 6 which also makes sense because you start the span count at '0' each time you create a new row-fluid class.